# Crash Event trends is increased even i have disabled Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Step 1: In Application Class

```
 override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        disableCrashlytics()
 } 

 private fun disableCrashlytics() {

        val crashlyticsCore = CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
                .disabled(true)
                .build()
  Fabric.with(this,Crashlytics.Builder().core(crashlyticsCore).build())
 }
```

I have disabled Crashlytics in Firebase SDK so, i'm not receive report in Firebase Crashlytics it is working as expected but Crash in Event trends is increased, which is created bad impression in console.

**NOTE: My Issue is getting increased Number of Crash in Event Thread which is creating wrong impression for me, specially when application is in developing mode.**

Answer (score 0):

you have to disable crashlytics in the AndroidManifest.xml file as:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Comment: It is use for only for initialization of Crashlytics like you can see log in console like 
 I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful (if you not disabled)
 I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider Skipping initialization. (If you have disabled)

In fect i have also tried with this is seems not work for me.

Comment: For what its worth, you can always skip the crashlytics initialization altogether. Or, you can have it disabled in just Debug mode: 
CrashlyticsCore crashlyticsCore = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
                .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build();

Comment: yes but in debug mode also it's not working , actually this is a question, please check again.